# The order for inlineStyleRanges is wrong

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a react application that allows our users to input data into the Editor component provided by [draft-js](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js). I made my own toolbar component our user could interact with by passing functions that update the EditorState. I also need to be able to save the EditorState contents to our database. We're able to save the database by using the ff code:

```
const serialized = JSON.stringify(
   convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())
);
saveStringToDatabase(serialized);
```

and are able to restore the values from the database using

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => {
  if (!serializedEditorState) {
    return EditorState.createEmpty();
  }
  const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(serializedEditorState));
  return EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
});
```

. All is good in the user interacting with the Editor component from the front-end.

Now the problem is when I try to restore the data saved in the database to the front-end, I get a wrong snapshot of the state editor. I'm suspecting it's because the result of the convertToRaw() function has the wrong order for blocks[index].inlineStyleRanges. In my attached screenshot, index 3  of inlineStyleRanges of the blocks object should be index 4 and index 4 should be in index 3. I think I might be using the wrong functions for updating the EditorState but can't confirm as I do not see any other resources describing the actual correct way to update EditorState. We update the editor state using the ff code:

```
const removedInlineStyle = Modifier.removeInlineStyle(
  editorState.getCurrentContent(),
  newSelection,
  inlineStyle,
);
const newInlineStyle = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(
  removedInlineStyle,
  newSelection,
  inlineStyle,
);
const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
  EditorState.acceptSelection(editorState, newSelection),
  newInlineStyle,
  'change-inline-style',
);
setEditorState(newEditorState);
```

[here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/3088) is a github issue of someone else that's experiencing something like mine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulZ4r.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.